# Install caffe on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: makefile, caffe, ubuntu-18.04

I'm installing caffe-cpu and anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version.

Anyway, I success to install Anaconda on my system, but I'm getting in trouble to install caffe.

I found many pages such as youtube, but it isn't helpful, so i read many times to official installation manual page [(I think here is the official page)](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html). In this page,

```
Installing Caffe from source

We may install the dependencies by merely one line
sudo apt build-dep caffe-cpu        # dependencies for CPU-only version
sudo apt build-dep caffe-cuda       # dependencies for CUDA version
```

It requires a deb-src line in your sources.list. Continue with [compliation](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation)

I can't know end line means. I tried to fix `/etc/apt/sources.list` as disabled
'#' part, but it's fail. I can't find the correct way on the internet. when I just follow the [compliation](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation) link, they say compliation with Make or CMake. I also don't know how to follow these information. I found some [makefile.config Github page](https://gist.github.com/pjspillai/87625e1b6a129335eb363a4131a301f2#file-caffe-installation-ubuntu-18-04-L34), it fails when I use `make all` command.

Could you give me some advice to help install caffe-cpu version? Thanks for read my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it working following these steps,

1. Get caffe source form here (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git)
2. Install CUDA if you need GPS support (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804)
3. Install CUDNN, if you need GPS support (https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download)
4. Replace existing Makefile.config with this (https://gist.github.com/GPrathap/1f9d184c55779509860b8bf92cea416d) Here I have configured for cuda 9.2. If you have a different version please search 9.2 and change the version which you have instaled. Also, please recheck all the paths which are declared in Makefile.config.
5. You may type `make all` followed by `make test`
6. `make distribute` for creating the final lib, an include directory of caffe which can be found in (caffe/distribute).
7. If you are using CMake type project add where to find caffe as bellow,

   ```
     set(Caffe_DIR "/home/software/caffe/distribute")   
     set(Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/software/caffe/distribute/include")  
     set(Caffe_LIBRARIES "/home/software/caffe/distribute/lib/libcaffe.so")
   ```
8. Add include directory `include_directories(${Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS})`
9. Add library `${Caffe_LIBRARIES}`
10. If you want to have another way of building it add PATH appropriately

Comment: Hello, Can you please list the dependencies that you have installed

Comment: If you have installed cuda, I guess you will no dependencies to be installed. Can't say it exactly. Try and let me know if you can't find any dependencies which you cant way to install

Comment: I have Ubuntu 18.04, CUDA 9.0 and CuDNN 7.4. As far as their official site (http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html) is concerned, they have mentioned to run 1 simple command to install caffe (with GPU support) i.e. either `sudo apt install caffe-cuda` or `sudo apt build-dep caffe-cuda`

But I haven't found anyone successfully installed it that way, Almost everyone used steps somewhat similar to this (https://gist.github.com/nikitametha/c54e1abecff7ab53896270509da80215) in order to install caffe in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Hello, I tried installing it but got stuck with error, I'm using this [caffe](https://github.com/rbgirshick/caffe-fast-rcnn). Getting this

[error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/njob5zq3p1ahnq1/error2.txt?dl=0), link to other files [Makefile.config](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ux8n6ds3fafxu1v/Makefile.config?dl=0), [Dependencies Installed](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3llv16byzoiinrr/dependency.txt?dl=0).

`Ubuntu 18.04`, `CUDA 9.0` and `CuDNN 7.4`

Comment: I added comments on your files

Answer (score 1):

You can append these deb-src lines in your source.list:

```
deb http://ftp2.cn.debian.org/debian sid main contrib non-free  
deb-src http://ftp2.cn.debian.org/debian sid main contrib non-free
```

If you get some public key errors, these commands will help you.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 04EE7237B7D453EC  
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the first part of the question, that is the automatic installation of the dependencies suggested by the official site, a simple way to cope with is the following:

1.type in terminal

```
software-properties-gtk
```

and in the appearing window make sure ***source code*** box is checked. This adds the vital lines to your sources.list file.

2. then you are able to run the corresponding command :

```
sudo apt build-dep caffe-cpu        # dependencies for CPU-only version
sudo apt build-dep caffe-cuda       # dependencies for CUDA version
```

An additional CLI method on adding the lines is proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list) (however modification within a docker image is recommended, which is limiting but probably prevents one from corrupting system files).